# Tesseract training: only few words

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I need to train tesseract to recognize just ten words.
Words are pharma name, thing like: Atrasil, Spectful 
Since fonts used are pretty common, I tried to unpack eng.traineddata, substitute freq-dawg and word-dawg with just those words. Then I've repack them into a new traineddata, unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work very well. Matching results are still unacceptable and I can't use them, even when I use images obtained from a simple word file.
Is there a way to achieve a good matching? do I need to remove other files from the unpack trained data?

Comment: I didn't down vote it but as this is VERY specific IMHO I;d propose to ask in the tesseract forums/usergroup ?

Comment: Thx Daji I will look there, but I' ve seen a lot of questions like that with tesseract as topic around here. Hate downvote when none explain the reason is like cowardy.

Comment: Have you tried the `bazaar` pattern? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674061/train-tesseract-for-specific-words-possible

Comment: Thank you @nguyenq I've read about it, but it doesn't seem to be added in ios version of tesseract.

Comment: You can create a `eng.user-words` file and make several `setVariable` calls to emulate the `bazaar` configuration settings.

Comment: Seems interesting, which variable should I call?

Comment: They are listed in the Tesseract [manual](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) page.